# In SOLR white space is giving different results

Tags: solr, lucene, removing-whitespace

I have tried many ways and searched in different sites but I didn't get any answer.

I need same results for *desk book* and *deskbook* and I have written as deskbook ,*desk book* => *deskbook*.
But I get *deskbook* results on one page and *book* results on another page. This is due to **Lucene** parser. I got this info from [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) link.

Comment: Could you post your queries example?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multiword synonym please check if you are following the below :-

> Keep in mind that while the SynonymFilter will happily work with
>   synonyms containing multiple words (ie: "sea biscuit, sea biscit,
>   seabiscuit") The recommended approach for dealing with synonyms like
>   this, is to expand the synonym when indexing.

So you have it during indexing time analysis only.

e.g.

use the same filter chain in both index and query time anaylsis, so the searched term matches the indexed terms.

e.g.

```
<fieldType name="text_synonym" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Thanks jay, but i tried this but it is not showing any results
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syms.txt"
     ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />

Comment: Have you applied the synonym filter during the index time analysis only ?

Comment: and the same does not apply on the query time ? Can you post the fields you are querying and the schema.xml definition.

Comment: <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syms.txt"
     ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">

    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
</analyzer>    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syms.txt"
     ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />